# Is there a way for me to use multiple WHERE statements to select total population for 7 races group by county?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

[image]

I have this dataset that I imported to MySQL and I want to select only the total population for each race group by county. So far I can only select the total population of two races grouped by county like the below syntax (I created a View named asian to join the table named ca_pop):

```
select ca.county as County, sum(ca.population) as 'White pop', a.Asian_pop as Asian from asian as a
join ca_pop as ca on ca.county = a.county
where ca.date_year = '2022' and ca.race = 'White, Non-Hispanic'
group by County
```

Here's the syntax I wrote to create the table for the imported dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE ca_pop(
county_code INT NOT NULL,
county VARCHAR(45) NULL,
date_year VARCHAR(4) NULL,
race_code INT NULL,
race TEXT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(6) NULL,
age INT NULL,
population INT NULL);
```

And here's the syntax to create the View:

```
create view asian as select county, sum(population) as Asian_Pop from ca_pop
where date_year = 2022 and race = 'Asian, Non-Hispanic'
group by county
```

Is there a way for me to use multiple Where statements to select the total population for each of the 7 races by county?

Comment: edit the question show Tables DDL , view, and complete sample data.

Comment: @OldProgrammer just edited the question, the dataset is too large for me to show, I can only show a small subset of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ca.county as County, sum(SELECT population FROM ca_pop GROUP BY  race ) as 'White pop', a.Asian_pop as Asian from asian as a
join ca_pop as ca on ca.county = a.county
where ca.date_year = '2022' and ca.race = 'White, Non-Hispanic'
group by County
```

Comment: It did not work for me, when I removed the subquery it worked but it does not show 7 columns for race and rows for counties.

Answer (score 0):

```
select county, race, sum(population)
from ca_pop
group by county, race
```